# How to call func renderer(_:didAdd:for:)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, arkit, coreml

I am working on a iOS app that uses ARKit and CoreML that's supposed to add a SCNNode after a certain number was recognised on the wall. The problem that I am facing right now is that I have two functions competing at the same time (one searching for a wall ( `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)` and another searching for the numbers (´´classificationCompleteHandler´´). That being said I only want the app to search and add a new ARAnchor after some conditions for example `if(lastNum != num && score > 0.90){ addNewARAnchor() }`. The thing is that I don't know what I should add in this `func addNewARAnchor()`. My idea was to add the function responsible for adding new ARAnchors which is `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` but I don't know which arguments I should use! So right now I have something like:

```
func addNewARAnchor(){
 if(lastNum != num && score >= 0.9){
  // I don't know how to call renderer
 }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor){
 //SCNNodes stuff
}
```

I don't know if this approach even works! I have though of using threads but I don't understand nothing at all about that... If you have any ideas I'm more than welcome to ear them! Thanks!

(If you would like I can edit this and can share all my code!)

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

is a delegate method and therefore you (typically) do not call it yourself. Instead, set the delegate of the session to some object. Then, whenever this function gets called run a bit of code:

```
guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
```

Then save the anchor in some array so that you can add to it later:

```
planeAnchors.append(planeAnchor)
```

Finally, when you need to use an anchor, search through the array and find which one is most useful to you.

---

Edit:
If you have a scene view called `sceneView`, you can set its delegate by doing the following in the view controller (or any other class):

```
sceneView.delegate = self
```

Then, to access the anchor, simply do:

```
let p = planeAnchors[0] // Or whichever anchor you want to access, you would just change the index
```

Finally, to add a node to that anchor:

```
let node = SCNNode()
node.position = SCNVector3Make(p.center.x, 0, p.center.z)
// Rotate because SceneKit is rotated
node.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
self.sceneView.addChildNode(node)
```

You can switch up this code a little depending on how you want to add the node/depending on the type of node. The point is that you use the anchors p.center.x and p.center.z properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to add something later. The numbers are on the wall you see? I want to display the content right after the number and the wall were detected. If I find the number and the wall -> SCNNode , If I find the number but not a wall -> Do nothing, if I find the wall but not the number -> Do nothing. My problem is that sometimes the app recognises the wall first and adds a ARAnchor to those coordinates and only then it recognise the number and so I have to find a new ARAnchor for the SCNNode to appear.

Comment: You do not have to find a new anchor if you save that anchor in an array and access it when you want to add the node.

Comment: Oh! I see! It seems I was the one who didn't understand! So, can you explain me a couple of things? What do you mean by "set the delegate to some object" and how can i add those nodes to a planeAnchor that is on a array ? Do you want me to share the code? Maybe like that you can understand what i mean by those questions..

Oh, and thank you very much!

Comment: Do you think like that it would work? Because what I want is for the node to be added right where the number is and the numbers are in completely diferente positions. So, if I'm correct, the renderer(_:didAdd:for:) is automatically called after a new vertical plane was found right? So even if I make p = planeAnchors.last-1 wouldn't I still have to find a new plane so that the node would still be added to where the number is? I don't know if I have mentioned but most of the times the nodes appears like it should, 100% correct, which is right where the number is.

Comment: is there way to delete planeAnchors from the SceneView? I could try to see if there were nodes added to the last planeAnchor that was added. If not , delete the planeAnchor so i can detect that wall again and create a new planeAnchor capable of showing the nodes.

Comment: renderer(_:didAdd:for:) gets called for every new anchor detected, therefore the latest anchor would most likely be the one that the camera is pointing at.

Comment: Just remove the anchor from your array.

Comment: Alright then! Let me see if I got things right! Create ``var planeAnchors: [ARAnchor] = []`` before ViewDidLoad(). Then after the ``guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }`` do ``planeAnchors.append(planeAnchor)``. After that do let ``p = planeAnchors.last`` and where I have ``let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)`` I change to ``CGFloat(p.center.x)`` right? At the end of the renderer I check there were any nodes created. If not I remove the planeAnchors last anchor. Everything right?

Comment: Yes try that out

Comment: Only plane anchors have that property.

Comment: Yeah sorry! After I posted the question I understood what I was doing wrong. planeAnchors should be`` [ARPlaneAnchor] ``and not `` [ARAnchor]`` as I said in the previous comment. Do you think there is a difference between doing ``node.addChildNode(planeNode)`` (I am doing like this) and ``self.sceneView.addChildNode(planeNode)`` as you said before?

Comment: You should be fine doing that